# How to dev a local package in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am reading through the docs for working with local packages and it is unclear as to what syntax I would use to add a locally developed package. My package currently has a git repo but I want to point the dev version to the local copy as the one on git is not up to date. I read the docs here: https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/managing-packages/#Adding-a-local-package but they do not specific the syntax to use. I tried something like:

```
mypackage) pkg> dev /Users/myuser/Desktop/mypackage
ERROR: package `mypackage [6b2b467d]` has the same name or UUID as the active project
```

Is this the right syntax or am I missing something?

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that you can't dev the package locally if it is already activated. I switch to my default 1.6 environment and:

```
(@v1.6) pkg> dev /Users/myuser/Desktop/mypackage
```

worked!

Comment: Coue you point to the documentation of this?

Comment: It doesn't exist, I opened a PR here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/pull/2847